# How to prevent floated div from "dropping down"?

Tags: html, css

Ive looked through previous similar questions and none seem to get me the result I need.

This is the layout Im trying to make...

[image: layout]

The issue is in the section that says ORIGINS and has the image.

There is one containing div that contains 2 child divs. One child floated left with the text and one floated right with the image.

When you scale the window I want the divs to scale too.

The problem is when you scale the window to a certain point the right child drops below the left child.

I tried making the child's display:inline-block and the container overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap but then the text in the paragraphs flows outside the whole layout.

Here is the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <style>

        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        #container{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #main_content_container{
            padding: 0px 20px 40px 20px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            max-width: 1090px;
            background-color: white;
            overflow: auto;
         }

         #main_content_left_col{
             width: 65.1%;
             margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
             float: left;
         }

         #main_content_right_col{
             width: 33%;
             margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
             float: right;
         }

        #history_pic{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
        }            

        p{
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', serif; font-weight: 300;
            color: black;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: justify;

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="main_content_container">

            <div id="main_content_left_col">

                <h1>ORIGINS</h1>

                <h2>A look at the history of wave sliding</h2>

                <p>The riding of waves has likely existed since humans began swimming in the ocean. In this sense, bodysurfing is the oldest type of wave-catching. Standing up on what is now called a surfboard is a relatively recent innovation developed by the Polynesians. The influences for modern surfing can be directly traced to the surfers of pre-contact Hawaii.</p>

                <p>The art of surfing, called he'enalu in the Hawaiian language, was first described in 1769 by Joseph Banks on the HMS Endeavour during the third voyage of Captain James Cook. Surfing was a central part of ancient Polynesian culture and predates European contact. The chief (Ali'i) was the most skilled wave rider in the community with the best board made from the best tree. The ruling class had the best beaches and the best boards, and the commoners were not allowed on the same beaches, but they could gain prestige by their ability to ride the surf on their ratchet boards.</p>

                <p>The sport was also recorded in print by other European residents and visitors who wrote about and photographed Samoans surfing on planks and single canoe hulls; Samoans referred to surf riding as fa'ase'e or se'egalu. Edward Treager also confirmed Samoan terminology for surfing and surfboards in Samoa. Oral tradition confirms that surfing was also practiced in Tonga, where the late king Taufa'ahau Tupou IV was the foremost Tongan surfer of his time.</p>

            </div>

            <div id="main_content_right_col">

                <img id="history_pic" src="http://i1370.photobucket.com/albums/ag265/arsinek1/web_development/history_pic_zpsmy5pfaet.jpg" />

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You may want to try removing `float` if you're also considering using `inline-block`, having both present is usually unnecessary! Try to get the layout working correctly without floats.

Comment: I did that. The text then flowed out of its container and off the page.

Comment: The issue is that you should set the all the inner-tags inside the two divs property position:relative;

Comment: @ Malik Just tried that and the text still flows outside its divs

Comment: One suggestion is that you use the built in CSS/JS files-collection.
from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) and read its document. It is a great documented website for the new ones. Quick to learn and Quick to build new responsive websites. A lot of features included @Arsinek (i will be available to teach that relevant documentation part, which you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, inline-block can be a good fit. But there are few things, you'll need to change the margin to padding and add box-sizing: border-box; in order to get the total width not to exceed the container.

It should be max-width: 100%; rather than width: 100%; Also read the comments inside the CSS code.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5Lad2psj/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#main_content_container {
    padding: 0px 20px 40px 20px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 1090px;
    background-color: white;
    /* overflow: auto; */
    /* font-size: 0; */ /*enable this if necessary - to fix spacing issue*/
}
#main_content_left_col {
    width: 65.1%;
    /* margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; */
    /* float: left; */
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* font-size: 16px; */ /*if it's set to 0 on the parent, you'll need this*/
}
#main_content_right_col {
    width: 33%;
    /* margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px; */
    /* float: right; */
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* font-size: 16px; */ /*if it's set to 0 on the parent, you'll need this*/
}
#history_pic {
    /* width: 100%; */
    margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-family:'Roboto', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, that did the trick. Are we really not supposed to say thanks? Seems weird. Also, saying "Thanks, that worked" seems like it could be useful information because it validates a response worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Bootstrap blocks . The pseudo code is :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="inner-content">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="span8">
            ....
          .....//the text content goes in here.
        </div

        <div class="span4">
            //div class for the image
        </div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Here you divide a block of div into two parts of which the *text* area gets *8 parts* of the *12 parts* and the remaining goes to the image i.e. *4 parts.*

The CSS for them is following(incase you don't have it) :

```
.container { padding: 0 15px !important;}

.inner_content { padding:25px 0 0 0;text-align:left;}

 .span8 {
    width: 770px;
  }
 .span4 {
    width: 370px;
  }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row {
    margin-left: -30px;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
```

Comment: I hear the term bootstrap a lot but dont know anything about it. Is that something all browsers natively support or is it some sort of plugin or what?

Comment: it is a set of CSS class and JS that Twitter employees made for the web developers who have to worry about the back end than worrying much about the front end . Visit www.getbootstrap.com/css for more information on it!

Answer (score 0):

**Try following changes. This will work for you**

```
     #main_content_left_col{
         width: 62.1%;
         margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
         float: left;
         display: inline-block;
     }

     #main_content_right_col{
         width: 33%;
         //margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
         //float: right;
         display: inline-block;
     }
```

Answer (score -5):

Perhaps you should try using a table instead of DIVs. This seems like an instance where it would be far more efficient.

Comment: Tables are for tabular data.

Comment: Tables are generally used for data.